# Why is reputation requirements for creating tags, different on other Stackexchange Sites?

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed that on different stackexchange sites, reputation requirements for creating tags vary and differ.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different reputation requirements for private betas, public betas, graduated sites, Stack Overflow, and Meta SO.

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/172958)

Betas need different requirements because there just aren't many people with the rep to do anything at graduated levels, especially towards the beginning.